# AWS CDK cyclic reference for rest_api-lambda-rds stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-cdk, circular-dependency

My setup looks like this:

```
*Main Stack*
RestApi
VPC (2 subnets, one public, one private_isolated)
DBStack
LambdaStack
```

```
*DBStack*
ServerlessCluster (in private_isolated VPC subnet)
```

```
*LambdaStack*
LayerVersion
lambda.Function (in private_isolated VPC subnet)
```

The LambdaStack also (after creating the function) registers a new route through `api.root.addResource()` and a method through `rest_endpoint.addMethod("GET/POST/...", LambdaIntegration(lambaFunction))` as well as a `database.connections.allowDefaultPortFrom(lambdaFunction)`.

When I try to synth this, I get the following error msg:

```
Error: 'MainStack/lambdastack' depends on 'MainStack' (no description provided, no description provided, no description provided, no description provided, no description provided, no description provided). Adding this dependency (MainStack -> MainStack/lambdastack/lambda_function/Resource.Arn) would create a cyclic reference.
```

I can "fix" this by removing the rest_endpoint.addMethod() call (which is obviously not an option).

My questions are the following:

1. How to fix it (obviously)
2. How would I go about debugging this myself as all the usual resource descriptions are "no description provided" here)

I tried different levels of separation (all in one file, a lot of stacks...) which all made no difference.

Comment: What type of construct do `DBStack` and `LambdaStack` subclass?  What is the `scope` (first arg) of the two?

Comment: Both are subclasses of "Stack" and have MainStack (also subclassing Stack) as their scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thanks in part to [fedonev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103511/fedonev) (moving all stacks one layer up) and some rather lucky finds in the AWS docs, here is what now works well:

- everything is in one stack for now
- i had to add an interface endpoint to the private_isolated vpc for the secret manager

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

`LambdaStack` can't be deployed before `MainStack`, because it needs the `MainStack` VPC.  But neither can `MainStack` be deployed first, because it needs the function reference from `LambdaStack`.  This is the "cyclic reference" in the error.

The easiest fix is to put your entire app into a single stack.  Alternatively, refactor your app such that the inter-stack dependencies run in one direction only.  The CDK [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-separate) docs address the "How many stacks?" question.

If you do end up keeping multiple stacks, consider making the `App` the common scope for all the stacks, rather than nesting them.  I have not seen `Stack` constructs (other than [NestedStacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.NestedStack.html)) built as parent-child.  This may not result in errors, but at a minimum [does not seem idiomatic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stacks.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake to use MainStack where i should have used App; 
If i put everything in one Stack it (kind of) works. It is deploying successfully, but the database is not ready when the lambda function is deployd and i cannot use the secret. If i add a dependency on the database im back to the cyclic reference, even if i put VPC and DB in their own Stack.